# Gostaria de iterar sobre um objeto do Beautiful soup, porém no final ele da um erro no find() por ser uma lista. Como eu poderia resolver este erro?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def get_object(url):
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,'html.parser')
    return soup


def get_all_links_players(bsObject):
    
    links_a = bsObject.find("td",class_ = "headcol no_sorter").findAll( "a")
    urls = [i.get("href") for i in links_a]
    return urls    

def get_links_players():
    
    links = ["https://www.mlb.com/stats" + "/?page" + "=" + str(i) for i in range(1,7)]
    result = [requests.get(i).text for i in links]
    bsObject = [BeautifulSoup(i,"lxml") for i in result]  
    all_players = [i.get("href") for i in bsObject.find("tbody",class_ = "notranslate").find_all("a")]
    return all_players
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    for i in get_links_players():
        print(i)
```

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: O `find` não está definido para lista, de fato. Você deve aplicar o find para cada elemento na lista. Se você trocar a linha 23 por `all_players = [i.get("href") for i in bsObject[0].find("tbody",class_ = "notranslate").find_all("a")]`, o programa printa o número dos players para esse elemento. Mas não está claro o que você está fazendo, então fica difícil responder. Se puder, explique melhor

Comment: Então, estou fazendo um web scraping dos jogadores de baseball da mlb. Eu consegui iterar sobre todas as paginas das estatísticas dos jogadores, assim quero pegar cada link de cada jogador e construir um bd com com todos os detalhes de cada jogador.